# JavaFx. How to change the position of a check-box?

Tags: java, javafx

I create a check-box,

```
    Group g1 = new Group();
    CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox("Check-box");
     chk1.setIndeterminate(true);
    g1.getChildren().add(chk1);
    root.getChildren().add(g1);
```

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html

I can see the  methods `setLayoutX` and `setLayoutY` in the Section: `Methods inherited from class javafx.scene.Node`

However, when I try to set the position of my check-box:

```
chk1.setLayoutX();
```

I got an error:

```
Method "setLayoutX" in Class Node cannot be applied to the given class.
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this problem and how to set the position of the check-box?

Comment: @James_D. Thank you for your help once again. :-)  I have fixed this problem: chk1.setLayoutX(AN INTEGER);

Comment: Ah, good, I just figured out what the error was too.